# Opening port for webservice in CentOS

Tags: centos

I'm trying to open port for webservice in CentOS to access on the same network. Ports 8443 and 8446, they should be open and listening **netstat -an | grep "LISTEN"** results in:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8443            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8446            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9999            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

And all traffic should be allowed **iptables -L** gives

```
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
```

I can access 8080 and 9999 but not 8443 or 8446.

**EDIT:** output of **iptables -L -n | less**

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5432

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5432
```

Comment: post output of:    iptables -L -n | less

Comment: @imvikasmunjal sorry for the late response, edited the answer

Comment: You effectively don't have a firewall, because it accepts everything. But your question is missing some important details: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: Problem is that I can't access my webserver from another computer on the same network, ports  8443 and 8446 (https). Altough I can do it from http ports 8080 and 9999. Ports 8443 and 8446 work fine when accessing from localhost but not working with network computers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to flush every iptables chain:

```
iptables -F -t nat
iptables -F -t filter
iptables -F -t mangle
```

and configure iptables chain to ACCEPT everything by default:

```
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
```

if you can't access to the webserver  after clear iptables rules the problem isn't the firewall (iptables)